# WPF passing binding to a shared template from DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf

The [following question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f84e0efd-b1f2-4ab6-9af7-41fa95b5315d/how-to-set-data-binding-for-a-shared-datatemplate?forum=wpf) basically exactly describes my problem. I need some new takes on this.

In the question, they say `DataTemplateSelector` could work for this, but it could only automate the template selection logic, it doesn't help with the data binding issue. The [example here](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Data%20Binding/DataTemplatingIntro/TaskListDataTemplateSelector.cs) is just extremely bad code by the way. (really, looking up the resource in the current main window? it should be looked up next to the element.)

The question rephrased: **how do I share a single template that's in resources across multiple columns of a data grid, with databinding support, that is, I want to be able to specify, at the data column level, to which property the control in the instantiated template should bind, without copy-pasting the template definition in each of the columns?**

I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044106/wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-shared-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826739/wpftoolkit-datagridtemplatecolumn-template-binding), I have tried implementing a solution both with and without the rerouting via a custom binding attached property implemented in the second question, both with and without a nested template definition. When I'm trying to access `RelativeSource` to reach out for the attached property on the parent, it says `Binding.RelativeSource cannot be set while using Binding.StaticSource`. This might be because the questions use WPF Toolkit, while I'm using the default data grid controls. [My markup](https://github.com/AntonC9018/uni_gui/blob/b57407b7622fa715428ae0df8b5401a4e47d36b6/lab1/Form1.xaml#L40-L62), [my attached property definition](https://github.com/AntonC9018/uni_gui/blob/b57407b7622fa715428ae0df8b5401a4e47d36b6/lab1/Form1.xaml.cs#L44-L59). To be clear, if I do it the dumb, copy-paste way, the cells show the date picker perfectly fine.

It would've been awesome to be able to do something like that, but I failed to make it work so far:

```xml
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="datePicker">
        <StackPanel>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ???}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid Name="CarDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Header="ManufacturedOn"
            ???="{Binding Path=ManufacturedDate}"
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource datePicker}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381753/wpf-datagrid-creating-a-new-custom-column

Comment: @ASh, are you saying you can't do this with templates? The link you sent has a custom column implementation. Is there maybe a way to combine the custom implementation , the template and the binding?

Comment: I think that I personally can do this with templates. But it would take me a few hours of work, and before going that way I would try to implement custom column type